# Why does apt-cache rdepends --installed list uninstalled packages?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running apt-cache rdepends to determine which packages are essential on my machine.

For `alex`, I got the following:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends alex --installed
alex
Reverse Depends:
    alex:i386
```

The problem is that `alex:i386` is actually not installed. Why would it show up? What am I doing or understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `apt-cache`.

`apt-cache rdepends alex` shows

```
alex
Reverse Depends:
  haskell-platform
    alex:i386
  haskell-platform
    alex:i386
```

`alex:i386` isn’t part of the reverse-dependency chain (there is no chain here, since `--recurse` wasn’t used); it’s shown because [it’s another solution](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/f15e090301e0744471d0fbf86ea0d494f6c08215/apt-private/private-depends.cc#L110) for the dependency.

Adding `--installed` [filters out](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/f15e090301e0744471d0fbf86ea0d494f6c08215/apt-private/private-depends.cc#L83) the `haskell-platform` lines, but not the `alex:i386` lines...

The next release of `apt` from the `master` branch [will include a fix for this](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/commit/c74d1ee6dc7e7139f243cd57e258f51b3677d59c).